# Changing the file extension to .pdf

Tags: gnuplot

I've written a script that iterates  all the files in a directory and plots them. The output is `.pdf`. Since I pass the file names as argument, I need to change the output's extension.

For instance: when I plot `file1.dat`, the output is `file1.dat.pdf`. But I don't want `.dat` part.

I can concatanate strings in gnuplot script but how to remove the extension(last 4 characters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gnuplot you have some string function which you can use. In your case you have several options:

1. Pass only the basename of the file so that you can do `set output file.'.pdf'; ... plot file.'.dat'`
2. Remove the last four characters: `set output file[:strlen(file)-4].'.pdf'`
3. Search only for `.dat`: `set output file[:strstrt(file, '.dat')].'.pdf'`

etc.

Comment: `set output file[:strstrt(file, '.dat')].'.pdf'` should be `set output file[:strstrt(file, '.dat')-1].'.pdf'`